# Java get Border color and size

Tags: swing, colors, size, border

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 2));
Border border = tf.getBorder();
```

How can I get border color and size?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible, sadly.

Answer (score 5):

To get the border color:

```
 ((LineBorder)JTextField.getBorder()).getLineColor();
```

and this just a thought about how to get  the border size, if you assume that the border size is the same as the component size you can cast JTextField to JComponent and get the size of JTextField:

```
 ((JComponent)JTextField).getSize();
```

but you should use it after putting the JTextField in its container, otherwise it will return (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 2));
LineBorder border = (LineBorder) tf.getBorder();
System.out.println("Border color = "+  border.getLineColor() 
                          + "  size= " + border.getThickness());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border.getBorderInsets(JTextField).bottom
border.getBorderInsets(JTextField).left
border.getBorderInsets(JTextField).right
border.getBorderInsets(JTextField).top
border.getLineColor()
```

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, but this is the only solution that actually works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
JTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 20));
```

Comment: I think you misread the question... he wants to *get* the `border` size and *color*.